# Как в строковой переменной удалить первую строку?

Tags: bash

Как в строковой переменной удалить первую строку? То есть в переменной хранится текст в несколько строк. Нужно первую строку удалить. Нужно сделать без записи в файл

Comment: метки *sh* (posix-совместимые оболочки «вообще») и *bash* (конкретная реалиазация такой оболочки) — несовместимы. оставил более частную — *bash*. если вы подразумевали именно *sh*, то замените.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, не соглашусь, я читаю это как «как сделать X в `sh` и, если нормального способа нет, то конкретно в `bash`», так что

Comment: @Fat-Zer, придумать вопрос, в котором будут уместны обе метки, несложно. помимо того примера, что вы привели, можно хоть и так: «почему фича икс работает в *sh*, но не работает в *bash* (или наоборот)». но мы тут вроде как собрались не придумывать свой вопрос, а отвечать на уже заданный.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, я про то что именно этот вопрос так прочитал т.к. были поставлены обе метки... также оно поощряет в ответе указывать, что универсально, а что является расширением `bash`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

да как обычно:

```
$ text=$(echo -e '1\n2\n3')
$ echo "$text"
1
2
3
$ echo "${text#*$'\n'}"
2
3
```

для справки: `$ man bash`, "Remove  matching  prefix  pattern": `${parameter#word}`.

ну или в [стандарте posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), "Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern": `${parameter#[word]}`. и если это актуально для вашего случая (не используете что-нибудь современное типа *bash/zsh*), то придётся вместо `$'\n'` вставить в текст скрипта непосредственно «перевод строки»:

```
echo "${text#*
}"
```

Comment: не совсем честный ответ: в `text` здесь не хранится «текст в несколько строк», как в условии... так что для чего-то вроде `text="$(cat /my/file)"` он совсем не подойдёт...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, исправил. для обратной совместимости можно использовать `$(printf '\n')` вместо `$'\n'`

Comment: мм... не знал про такой (`$'\n'`) экспаншн, даже не вижу, где он в `man`'е описан... `$(printf '\n')` как и `$(echo)` кстати не работает ни в `bash`'е ни в `dash`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ищите строку `$'`

Answer (score 1):

Например можно с помощью `sed`'а:

```
VAR="$(echo "$VAR" | sed '1d')"
```

Comment: так тоже должно сработать, `VAR=$(sed '1d' <<< "$VAR")`

Comment: @PotroNik, да, но `<<<` —  bash'изм

Comment: `tail -n +1` тоже должно сработать.